# Error: No network specified. Cannot determine current network. for Truffle Migrate

Tags: truffle, truffle-migration

I am getting this error for `truffle migrate`.

```
truffle migrate
Error: No network specified. Cannot determine current network.
    at Object.detect (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/truffle/build/webpack:/packages/truffle-core/lib/environment.js:31:1)
    at /usr/local/lib/node_modules/truffle/build/webpack:/packages/truffle-core/lib/commands/migrate.js:91:1
    at finished (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/truffle/build/webpack:/packages/truffle-workflow-compile/index.js:53:1)
    at /usr/local/lib/node_modules/truffle/build/webpack:/packages/truffle-compile/index.js:314:1
    at /usr/local/lib/node_modules/truffle/build/webpack:/packages/truffle-compile/profiler.js:158:1
    at /usr/local/lib/node_modules/truffle/build/webpack:/~/async/dist/async.js:3888:1
    at /usr/local/lib/node_modules/truffle/build/webpack:/~/async/dist/async.js:473:1
    at replenish (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/truffle/build/webpack:/~/async/dist/async.js:1006:1)
    at iterateeCallback (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/truffle/build/webpack:/~/async/dist/async.js:995:1)
    at /usr/local/lib/node_modules/truffle/build/webpack:/~/async/dist/async.js:969:1
    at /usr/local/lib/node_modules/truffle/build/webpack:/~/async/dist/async.js:3885:1
    at /usr/local/lib/node_modules/truffle/build/webpack:/packages/truffle-compile/profiler.js:154:1
    at /usr/local/lib/node_modules/truffle/build/webpack:/~/async/dist/async.js:1140:1
    at /usr/local/lib/node_modules/truffle/build/webpack:/~/async/dist/async.js:473:1
    at iteratorCallback (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/truffle/build/webpack:/~/async/dist/async.js:1064:1)
    at /usr/local/lib/node_modules/truffle/build/webpack:/~/async/dist/async.js:969:1
    at /usr/local/lib/node_modules/truffle/build/webpack:/~/async/dist/async.js:1137:1
    at /usr/local/lib/node_modules/truffle/build/webpack:/packages/truffle-compile/profiler.js:133:1
    at FSReqWrap.oncomplete (fs.js:155:5)
ayman@ayman-HP-Pavilion-Laptop-15-cc0xx:~/Desktop/InOut/voting$ truffle migrate
Error: No network specified. Cannot determine current network.
    at Object.detect (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/truffle/build/webpack:/packages/truffle-core/lib/environment.js:31:1)
    at /usr/local/lib/node_modules/truffle/build/webpack:/packages/truffle-core/lib/commands/migrate.js:91:1
    at finished (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/truffle/build/webpack:/packages/truffle-workflow-compile/index.js:53:1)
    at /usr/local/lib/node_modules/truffle/build/webpack:/packages/truffle-compile/index.js:314:1
    at /usr/local/lib/node_modules/truffle/build/webpack:/packages/truffle-compile/profiler.js:158:1
    at /usr/local/lib/node_modules/truffle/build/webpack:/~/async/dist/async.js:3888:1
    at /usr/local/lib/node_modules/truffle/build/webpack:/~/async/dist/async.js:473:1
    at replenish (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/truffle/build/webpack:/~/async/dist/async.js:1006:1)
    at iterateeCallback (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/truffle/build/webpack:/~/async/dist/async.js:995:1)
    at /usr/local/lib/node_modules/truffle/build/webpack:/~/async/dist/async.js:969:1
    at /usr/local/lib/node_modules/truffle/build/webpack:/~/async/dist/async.js:3885:1
    at /usr/local/lib/node_modules/truffle/build/webpack:/packages/truffle-compile/profiler.js:154:1
    at /usr/local/lib/node_modules/truffle/build/webpack:/~/async/dist/async.js:1140:1
    at /usr/local/lib/node_modules/truffle/build/webpack:/~/async/dist/async.js:473:1
    at iteratorCallback (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/truffle/build/webpack:/~/async/dist/async.js:1064:1)
    at /usr/local/lib/node_modules/truffle/build/webpack:/~/async/dist/async.js:969:1
    at /usr/local/lib/node_modules/truffle/build/webpack:/~/async/dist/async.js:1137:1
    at /usr/local/lib/node_modules/truffle/build/webpack:/packages/truffle-compile/profiler.js:133:1
    at FSReqWrap.oncomplete (fs.js:155:5)
```

This is my truffle.js file

```
// Allows us to use ES6 in our migrations and tests.
require('babel-register')

module.exports = {
  networks: {
    ganache: {
      host: 'localhost',
      port: 8545,
      network_id: '*' // Match any network id
      //gas: 470000
    }
  }
}
```

**Truffle Version - 6.4.1**

Comment: Do you have ganache running?

Comment: I replaced ganache with development....but I am getting the error `Error: Don't set config.from directly. Instead, set config.networks and then config.networks`

Answer (score 2):

Please try to run it with the following code, replacing ganache with development.

```
module.exports = {
networks: {
development:{
host:"localhost",
port: 8545,
network_id: "*"
}}};
```

Answer (score 0):

Default network in truffle is `development`.

In order to run command on different network, you need to specify network in command `truffle migrate --network ganache`